# Anyway to convert labels from a polygon layer to a point layer

Tags: polygon, labeling, point

I have a polygon layer of water bodies with a name attribute. I would like to create a points layer from the polygon that will display the water body names.

I can't use the polygon layer to display the names because the software I am using to process the shapefile into a readable format for my chartplotter does not process an area with text. It only process text fields for points or lines.

I am using QGIS 3.0.

Comment: Have you tried the centroids tool in Vector - Geometry?

Comment: no i haven't . i'm pretty new to all this. could you explain further

Comment: You may wish to spend some time with [the training manual](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/training_manual/), as it will walk you through a lot of basic operations like this. This site is where you come after the standard procedures fail, not where you start your research.

Answer (score 1):

[The QGIS Documentation](https://www.qgis.org/en/docs/index.html) is always the best place to start, especially for someone new to the program.

What you're looking for is the **Centroids** command, found in *Vector geometry* in the processing toolbox. In the docs, it is discussed [here](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing/vector_menu.html#geometry-tools).

Simply run the tool with your polygon layer as the input. Attributes will carry over into the output and can be labelled appropriately, as shown below.

[image: centroid dialog]

[image: output]

Comment: @JasonBlanchard Glad to hear it. Please click the green checkmark to get this off the "unanswered questions" list.